# How to create correct multi mapping query in dapper.net

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I'm creating simple application, which helps organise my flavours for mixing own e-liquids. I have three tables in localDb:

### Flavour:

*Id, Name, Company, Shop, Amount*

### Recipe:

*Id, Name, Date*

### RecipeFlavours(connects Flavours and Recipes in relation one to many)

*Id, FlavourId, RecipeId, PercentageAmount*

Also I provided models:

### Flavour:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Shop { get; set; }
    public double? Amount { get; set; }
```

### Recipe:

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Flavour, double?> RecipeElements { get; set; }
```

### RecipeElement:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public Flavour Flavour { get; set; }
public double? PercentageAmount { get; set; }
```

I perform query to fetch all of the recipes from database:

```
    public IEnumerable<Recipe> GetAll(){
        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT f.*, r.*, rf.PercentageAmount FROM Recipe r INNER JOIN RecipeFlavours rf ON rf.RecipeId = r.Id INNER JOIN Flavour f ON rf.FlavourId = f.Id";
        var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Recipe>();
        Db.Query<Recipe, Flavour,ElementRecipe, Recipe>(sqlQuery, (r, f, rf) =>{
            Recipe recipe;
            if(!lookup.TryGetValue(r.Id,out recipe))
                lookup.Add(r.Id, recipe = r);
            if(r.RecipeElements == null)
                recipe.RecipeElements = new Dictionary<Flavour, double?>();
            recipe.RecipeElements.Add(f,rf.PercentageAmount);
            return recipe;

        },splitOn: "RecipeId, FlavourId, Id, Id, Id");



        return lookup.Values.ToList();
    }
```

When query is executing, I'm getting exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Dapper.dll

Additional information: When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id
```

I can't recognize what I'm doing wrong. I was learning from this site: http://jsm85.github.io/tutorial/2016/04/13/map-multi-join-sql-query-using-dapper/

Comment: Consider using Entity Framework. Dapper is for optimization.

Comment: I don't think you need the splitOn. You only need to split into your main entities, and they all have a column called Id.